# How can you find a coefficient “$k$” to $f(x)=\sin(x)*k$ so that it includes a point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

In the function $f(x)=\sin(x)*k$, how do you find $k$ so that the function includes $A(-1;-1)$ or any point generally?

Through trial and error I found that in $f(x)=\sin(kx)$ if you wanted it to pass $A(-1;-1)$ $k=\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I don’t know how you would find $k$ for any other point.

Is there a formula or a trick to find $k$ in these functions?
If not, could someone compute $k$ for the first example: $f(x)=\sin(x)*k$ passing through $A(-1;-1)$? I have found it should be about $1.18$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: $g_k(x)=k\sin x$ will always be $0$ at points where $\frac x\pi$ is an integer. For all other values of $a$, the graph of $g_k$ passes through $(a,b)$ if and only if $k=\frac b{\sin a}$.

Comment: You have mixed up $\sin (k\cdot x)$ and $k\sin(x)$ a few times in the body and title, would you like to clarify which one you are studying?

Comment: I am studying k sin(x), and my question was answered by Giulio Sassatelli, I was using sin(kx) as an example of a value of k I managed to figure out through trial and error, but I didn’t know how you’d find k in neither of them. As sin(x)*k is now clear to me, does anyone know how to find k in sin(kx) to make the function include any point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plug the $x$-coordinate of the given point into the function you end up with a (linear) equation where $k$ is the only unknown, and it's quite easy to solve for. (Assuming the $x$-coordinate is not a zero of $\sin$)

Comment: I have no idea how I hadn’t thought of that. Thank you very much.